# Difference between any[ ] and any[ ] = [ ]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, class

In TypeScript, what is the difference between `stations: any[];`  and  `stations: any[] = [];`

```
export class RoleConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {
   stations: any[];
   stations: any[] = [];
}
```

**Can please anyone explain this.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`stations: any[];`**

The above denotes the **`stations`** is of **`type array of any`** but its **NOT** initialized

**`stations: any[] = [];`**

The above denotes you are **`initializing`** stations to  an **`empty array`**.